# How to run a JavaExec gradle task with arguments when the task is called in finalizedBy?

Tags: java, gradle, flyway, gradle-task

I created a JavaExec task that connects to a db and does some checks. In my flyway build.gradle I call the task like this:

```
flywayMigrate.finalizedBy(rootProject.checkOracleStandards)
```

The task works fine, but the problem is that the connection url, user and password are hardcoded in the program that connects to the db and does the checks. I want to pass them as args to the custom task.

How to run the custom task with args after flywayMigrate?

This is how my task gradle file looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    implementation rootProject.files("libs/check-oracle-db-standards-1.jar")

    implementation group: 'com.oracle.database.jdbc', name: 'ojdbc8', version: '21.3.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '5.3.13'
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
}

task checkOracleStandards(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'com.package.checkoracledbstandards.Main'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the best way to share/pass arguments between tasks is through files, have a task write them to a file somewhere, and then have your `checkOracleStandards` task load them from that file.

Make sure the arguments are written to the file in the `doLast` block, to avoid having the task run every time gradle syncs for example.

Finally, have your `checkOracleStandards` task open up the file, parse the parameters and use them somehow.

```
val outputPath = "${rootProjectPath}/build/check_params" <-- you may not want to use a folder for this
val paramFile = file("${outputPath}/check_params")

 doLast {
            if (paramFile.exists().not()) {
                paramFile.writeText()

                File(outputPath)
                    .walk()
                    .maxDepth(1)
                    .filter {
                        it.isFile
                                && it.name.endsWith("_params")
                    }
                    .forEach {
                        println("Passing params of ${it.name} into ${paramsFile.absolutePath}")
                        // PARSE params here
                        paramsFile.appendText("url: ${use_your_real_url}\tuser: ${use_your_real_user}\tpass: ${use_the_password}")
                        paramsFile.appendText("\n")
                    }
```

if unsure, should make this part of a "pass params" task to run before your `checkOracleStandards` task, and then just modify your `checkOracleStandards` task to read params from this file and use them.

EDIT:
lemme add some clarifications, unrelated to the answer itself - i would've just posted a comment; however SO changed something, and my browser is currently unable to leave comments anywhere, so i gave you an answer that should've just been a comment.

Comment: Trying it, but I was hoping something like this would work:
writeArgstoFile.finalizedBy "rootProject.checkOracleStandards --args=test"
:D

Comment: I will accept your answer, because I managed to run the custom task with args by writing to and reading from a file, but unfortunately there is a problem. This is how I write to file:
task writeArgstoFile {
    doFirst {
        mkdir "$rootProject.buildDir/check-db-standards"
        new File("${rootProject.buildDir}/check-db-standards/args").text = "${flyway.url}\n" +
                "${flyway.user}\n" +
                "${flyway.password}\n"
    }
}
I will always get the values that are written in the file and it will not update them in case flyway is run with -Dflyway.user=...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70350006/how-to-get-updated-flyway-values-when-running-flywaymigrate-with-properties

Comment: @DinuNicolae hey my comments are back, maybe i can help you out there too.