# How to get updated flyway values when running flywayMigrate with properties?

Tags: gradle, flyway

I want to write the flyway connection detail to a file, so I can use these values in a custom JavaExec task. If you want to know more about it you can read:
[How to run a JavaExec gradle task with arguments when the task is called in finalizedBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70346538/how-to-run-a-javaexec-gradle-task-with-arguments-when-the-task-is-called-in-fina/70346713#70346713)

I created a task that writes the url, user and password to a file and it works, but the problem is that it is always using the default values from the flyway {} block in the build.gradle file and ignores the overridden values in case flywayMigrate is run with props like this:

```
./gradlew flywayMigrate -Pflyway.user=admin -Pflyway.password=secret
```

Below you can see the task that writes the values to the file.

```
task writeArgstoFile {
    doFirst {
        mkdir "$rootProject.buildDir/check-db-standards"
        new File("${rootProject.buildDir}/check-db-standards/args").text = "${flyway.url}\n" +
                "${flyway.user}\n" +
                "${flyway.password}\n"
    }
}

flywayMigrate.finalizedBy(writeArgstoFile)
writeArgstoFile.finalizedBy(rootProject.checkOracleStandards)
```

How can I get the correct updated flyway values?

Comment: wont the `-P` set a temporary system variable? You will want to read [this](https://newbedev.com/how-to-pass-parameters-or-arguments-into-a-gradle-task)

Comment: Do note that, since you have a `flyway { ... }` block in your gradle script, `${flyway.user}` and `println flyway.user` will evaluate differently in that `doFirst`.

First one calling into the flyway block you defined, second one reading the parameter the task got.